How to Display Significant Symbols Only Above Corrplot.mixed Graphs?
I was plotting a graph form corrplot.mixed. After writing the scrip, I was not able to put the significant sigh only upper side of the graphs
corrplot.mixed(M, lower = "number", upper = "ellipse", order = 'AOE',p.mat = testRes$p, tl.pos = 'd',sig.level = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05),
pch.cex = 1.5, insig = 'label_sig', pch.col = 'black')
I am expecting to correct my problem ( ie I dont want the *** sing in lower part of the graphs
